# Test Lab support for testing HTML5 game in browsers on physical mobile devices

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-test-lab

does Firebase Test Lab enable/support (automated) testing of HTML5 browser based games on physical mobile devices? I would like to test my game in different browsers (IE, Chrome, FF, Safari) and different physical mobile devices (iOS, Android).
Does Firebase Testing Lab support that? And if it does, could anyone provide me an example or a tutorial how can it be done?

Best regards,
Mitja

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Test Lab supports testing of native apps on iOS and Android. It does not support testing of web apps.

From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/):

> With one operation, you can test your Android or iOS app across a wide variety of devices and device configurations

Comment: Thanks. I've hoped that I missed some information, but apparently not...